# Event bubbling up no matter what I try to do to stop it in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a React app and I am trying to prevent an event from bubbling.

```
  handleMessageClick(e) {
    if (this.state.person.liked === false) {
      this.launchErrorModal(
        "Error here"
      );
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();

      return false;
    }
  }
```

I've tried literally everything, switched my  to an , and nothing is working. As you can see I tried to stop propagation via any way I could as well. Nothing takes.

Here is my current link:

```
   <a
    href={this.createChatLink()}
     onClick={this.handleMessageClick}
    >
<element />

    </a>
```

Why won't propagation stop? If the condition is false, I just want to prevent the link from working.

I can confirm that handleMessageClick is ABSOLUTELY being called on click.

It's just... not doing anything.

Comment: Are your calls to e.preventDefault() being reached? perhaps `if (this.state.person.liked === false)` is throwing an exception?

Comment: have you tried to call `e.stopPropagation();` outside of the condition?

Comment: They're definitely being called because the error modal pops up, it just pops up AFTER redirection to the next page. I'll test with putting the propagation and such outside of the conditional and see if that changes anything

Comment: Nope, no change

Comment: I am noticing that when I am clicking on the link, the event that is propagating is on <element /> - but that's precisely what e.stopPropagation() should stop though...

Comment: We have no way to reproduce your problem. I suspect something else is at play here

Comment: Did you perhaps lose the `this` pointer on the call? Try replacing your configuration with `<a href=... onClick={(e) => this.handleMessageClick(e)}` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Nothing worked. Ultimately I just removed the href from the link, put preventDefault on the <a> directly (to maintain style), and put custom routing on my child element. It's hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that event bubbling is prevented under all circumstances, consider revising your code to this:

```
  handleMessageClick(e) {

    /* 
    Stop click event propagation immediatly, regardless of the value of 
    state.person.liked
    */
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    if (this.state.person.liked === false) {
      this.launchErrorModal(
        "Error here"
      );

      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Strange - any chance you can include source for `<element />`, with styling as well?